# Check if string matches a complex pattern

Tags: python, wordpress, python-3.x

Thank you for reading my question.

First of all, I use python 3.5 to write my code.

---

Recently, I have tried to read image file names, and each have a pattern format like:

> A01_[2016tokyo-tokyo-university-1_chuuoushokudo_1]_ori.jpg

and wordpress will add new post thumbnail for me, like

> A01_[2016tokyo-tokyo-university-1_chuuoushokudo_1]_ori-75x75.jpg

Furthermore, I use this pattern to rename my images.

> (english alphabet)(numbers) _ [(postname) _ (description) _ (number)] _ (ori or mod) _ (number).jpg

My question is, if I want to use this pattern to check whether I use the right way to rename my image, how can I do?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Try taking a look at Python's [re module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html). With a little work, it should help you achieve what you're looking for.

Before using this library, I would advise that you first read the [Regular Expression HOWTO](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html) article, as it will help you make sense of the `re` docs.